# "Practical" application of a somewhat impressive limit arising in elementary plane geometry

Tags: geometry, limits, applications

In [this question on one of the sister sites of m.s.e.](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7274/simple-real-world-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule-problem/11676#11676), the following problem is exhibited:

> From the point $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ on the unit circle, drop a perpendicular to the $x$-axis, and consider the region bounded by that perpendicular, the $x$-axis, and the arc from $(1,0)$ back to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. Ask what fraction of the area of that region is between the **chord** from $(1,0)$ to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and the **arc** from $(1,0)$ to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, and then take the limit of that fraction as $\theta\downarrow0.$

The only solution I know of involves either a routine application of L'Hopital's rule or a routine use of power series, and L'Hopital's rule must be iterated three times.

It is somewhat impressive because such a simply stated geometry problem can defy intuition so thoroughly and yet L'Hopital conquers it so neatly.

But in a comment under the question linked above, someone asked whether there is a "practical reason" why someone would want that limiting ratio.

I will construe that in the following way, and make it my present question:

**Is there a reason originating outside of this problem** – say in geometry or geodesy or astronomy or engineering or theoretical physics or statistics-applied-to-demography or whatever – for an interest in that limiting ratio?

Comment: I like this re-phrasing: Let $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$ be a minor arc of a circle, and let $M$ be the arc's midpoint. Find $$\lim_{B\to A}\;\frac{|\rm{cseg}AM| + |\rm{cseg} MB|}{|\rm{cseg}AB|}$$ where "$\rm{cseg}PQ$" is the [*circular segment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment) w/endpts $P$ & $Q$ (and "$|x|$" is the area of $x$). Neat generalizations: (1) Let $M$ divide the arc into lengths with ratio $p:q$. (2) Let $M_1,\ldots, M_{k-1}$, subdivide $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$ equally; find the limit replacing the ratio's numerator with the total of the $k$ smaller "cseg" areas.

Comment: @Blue : Instead of \rm{cseg} PQ you should write \operatorname{cseg} PQ. Then you get proper spacing in things like $A\operatorname{cseg} PQ$ and $A\operatorname{cseg}(PQ),$ where I include both of those two examples to show that the amount of space before and after $\operatorname{cseg}$ depends on the typographical context. If you will use the expression many times in one posting, just write \newcommand{\cs}{\operatorname{cseg}} at the beginning (inside MathJax) and thereafter if you type \cs PM in MathJax you'll see $\operatorname{cseg} PM. \qquad$

Comment: I started with `\operatorname`, but needed to free-up characters. I didn't realize `\newcommand` worked inside of comments. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Blue : I don't actually know if it works in comments. Let's try it: $\newcommand{\cs}{\operatorname{cseg}}$ blah blah blah $\cs PM.$ So there. $\qquad$

Comment: @Blue : . . . . . so it does. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for re-posting my comment as a question! At the moment I only have a (non-mathematical) opinion on it though; namely that there isn't a physical application of such limits, at least directly. The reason is that physically the sequence of ratios are not meaningful beyond a certain order of magnitude due to quantum effects. This differs from say limits corresponding to equilibrium states for differential equations.

Comment: @Blue: `\newcommand` and `\def` both work anywhere on the page in Math SE. However, beware that it affects everything that occurs on the page after it, even if it is posted by other people. It's not a good design, but there's nothing we can do about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know whether this truly qualifies as "*practical*", but the problem could be restated as...

> While approximating the area of a circle by areas of inscribed regular polygons, doubling the number of sides improves the accuracy of the approximation by a factor of $4$ asymptotically.

Indeed, let $S$ be the area of the circle, and $S_n$ be the area of the regular polygon with $n$ sides inscribed in the same circle. Then, with $\,\theta = \dfrac{2 \pi}{2 n}\,$,  the area of segment in question is $\,\dfrac{S - S_{2n}}{2n}\,$, and the given ratio (which can be proved to $\,\to 1/4)\,$, is $\,\dfrac{S - S_{2n}}{2n} \bigg/ \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{S - S_{n}}{n}\,$ $\,= \dfrac{S-S_{2n}}{S-S_n}\,$.